# std::lock_guard<pthread_mutex_t> does not compile

Tags: c++

```
std::lock_guard<pthread_mutex_t> lock(mExecutionReportsLock);
```

This does not compile because pthread_mutex_t is not valid template argument. What is the best way to achieve this functionality

Comment: The POSIX `pthread_mutex_t` is not a suitable type (it's not a class supporting the [requisite interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable)) for instantiating `std::lock_guard`, so the question makes no sense.  Further, the POSIX interface is a C API and never throws anything, so *if this were supported by an implementation* it would be up to a `std::lock_guard<>` implementation to specialise for `posix_mutex_t` and make its own choices....

Comment: You are saying that 
std::lock_guard<pthread_mutex_t> lock(mMyPthreadMutex);
would not work?

Comment: Exactly.  `pthread_mutex_t` is not even mentioned in the C++ Standard (none of pthreads is) - there's no requirement to support it in any form.  Still, a specific implementation *might* choose to do so (but I'd be very surprised).  Did you try it with your compiler?

Comment: Is there some lock_guard wrapper equivalent for me to use for a pthread_mutex_t type

Comment: Or is there a way I can use lock_guard by casting pthread_mutex_t to some other type

Comment: You can trivially write your own wrapper class to manage a `pthread_mutex_t` that satisfies the API requirements I linked above.  Have a go - tell us if you get stuck, somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111381/discussion-between-jonathon-hill-and-tony-d).

Comment: Sorry Jonathon - that's not a convenient mechanism for me at the moment.  Just google "C++ wrapper for pthread_mutex_t" and the first match explaining wrappers on wikipedia uses pthread_mutex_t as an example.  Should get you started.  (You might want to delete the copy constructor and `operator=`).

Comment: So what's the reason why you aren't using [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) (or [`std::recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) if recursive locking of the object is appropriate)?

Comment: One reason for using a naked pthread mutex would be to get prio inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::mutex m;

auto my_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
```

or...

```
using mutex_type = std::mutex;
using lock_type = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

mutex_type m;

auto lock = lock_type(m);
```